# Outlook 2010 Opening in SafeMode

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010

I am having problems with Outlook 2010 opening in Safe Mode.  I have gone on EVERY website and blog, tried EVERYTHING, and nothing seems to work.  Am I missing something here?

*Yes, I am having this problem with multiple PC's.

Comment: What kind of "problems" are you having? Links to some of the things you tried might also help.

Answer (score 3):

There was a Windows update sent out earlier this month that caused this (and it only affected Outlook 2010).  [KB3114409](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3114409) - "December 8, 2015, update for Outlook 2010 (KB3114409)"

[Here's an article form InfoWorld that discusses it](http://www.infoworld.com/article/3013219/microsoft-windows/microsoft-pulls-botched-patch-kb-3114409-that-triggered-problems-with-outlook-2010.html).

Blurb:

> Microsoft's Patch Tuesday update KB 3114409, intended to help admins
>   keep Outlook 2010 from starting in safe mode, has in fact done the
>   opposite. Many Outlook 2010 customers report that installing KB
>   3114409 forces Outlook to start in safe mode.

While uninstalling that update should fix it, Microsoft has since released another update that fixes the problem with that original update (yet keeps the other fixes involved that were not causing the problem).  So installing that is the better alternative...

That update is [KB3114560](https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/kb/3114560) - "December 16, 2015, update for Outlook 2010 (KB3114560)"

Listed under "Improvements and fixes":

> This update fixes an issue in which Outlook 2010 starts only in safe mode. This issue occurs after you install the December 8, 2015, update for Outlook 2010 (KB3114409).

Comment: Did this. However, there have been a few cases where the user reboots and the KB 3114409 update has reappeared.

Comment: You did what exactly?  Installed KB3114560?   Perhaps edit your question and expand on exactly what "tried everything" actually means, to avoid us just stating things you've already tried...

Comment: I apologize, getting frustrated.  I uninstalled KB3114409.  This does stop Outlook from opening in safe mode, for about a day. When I try to open Outlook the next day, it is back in safe mode and KB3114409 has reappeared.